# How do I earn the "Walk Your Own Path" achievement?

Tags: achievements, land-sliders

In Land Sliders, a game by PrettyGreat, I see no guidance on how to achieve the achievement "Walk your own path". The description accompanying the achievement is: "Start a REAL adventure".

If anyone has an idea of what this real adventure could be, I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this achievement (and it looks like others) are linked to a real-world scavenger hunt that the developers set the players on. Based on a forum post [here](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=271661&page=29), where people had been aggregating data, the way to unlock this specific achievement is this:

> This is amazing! birdfeet's image had three symbols on it, which brought us up to 9 total.
>
> I played around with different code combinations and finally found the one--or, at least, one that gave a response and also unlocked the "Walk Your Own Path" achievement.
>
> Spoilers for the code and what it gave me:
>
> If you number the symbols on the keypad 1-9, with the upper-left (left slash) being 1 and the bottom-right (E with dot) being 9, the code was:
>   9-9-8-4-7-5-7-3-4-2
>
> After [being input], a black screen with Land Sliders / Prettygreat appeared, along with the achievement. And this:
>   lna.payzyepiteiwblrrrdlazhxkq.ifq
>
> That looks like a website address? But maybe in code? If so, I have no idea what it translates to. Another puzzle??
>
> Image of the page that appeared: [image]

[This article](http://toucharcade.com/2016/01/22/land-sliders-arg-comes-to-an-end/) does a good job summarizing the entire adventure these players went on. Unfortunately, the "game" is now over, but the code above is what you need to unlock this achievement.